# Difference between char array declaration forms

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

we had this question in programming exam, and we are all debating the correct answer, soo what do you think?

3.1 Which of the following is an incorrect string initialization?

```
(a) char plant[] = "Tree";
(b) char plant[] = {'T','R','E','E'};
(c) char plant[80] = "Tree";
(d) char plant[80] = {'T','R','E','E'};
(e) None of the above
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hint: Some of them are missing terminating `'\0'` characters. Syntactical correctness, doesn't mean _it works_.

Comment: Look bro, I'm good enough to try them myself and I know without trying that b) misses a null char, the argument here is, are they all considered correct string initialization or not as they are all syntactically valid :)

Comment: Why don't you improve your poor question by these means then please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C99 and draft C11 standards define explicitly that a **string** is null-terminated: 7 Library 7.1.1 Definitions “A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.” The term “string” being so defined – and more than just a convention in the libraries – a “incorrect string initialization” (as referred to in the question) could be one that does not include a null character.

The C11 standard stipulates in 6.7.9 ¶22 “If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer.” C99 6.7.8 ¶22 says the same. This is the case in (b), which therefore is unterminated and incorrect:

```
char plant[] = {'T','R','E','E'};
```

6.7.9 /6.7.8 ¶21 that “If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration”; ¶10 says that such objects are filled with (various) zeroes; this implies that (c) and (d) are null-terminated:

```
char plant[80] = "Tree";
char plant[80] = {'T','R','E','E'};
```

6.7.9 / 6.7.8 ¶14 says “An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (**including the terminating null character** if there is room or **if the array is of unknown size**) initialize the elements of the array.” This implies that this (a) is null-terminated:

```
char plant[] = "Tree";
```

Answer (score 2):

They're all syntactically valid, but I'm assuming what the question is leaning towards is that `(b)` will simply create a `char [4]` - that is, it will not be null terminated, whereas the other three will be.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what happens, but some ppl would argue that its syntactically valid, therefore, they are all correct

Comment: Those people arguing would be wrong.  A valid string in C must be terminated with a null character.